# wordpress using WP MVC: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: permissions

I am using wordpress 4.0, localhost, WP MVC for plugin development.

I have a plugin named W2Store. It has three controllers, Countries, Currencies, Zones.

All the three were mereged into one single admin menu Mystores and the index page is working.
I have added a link to add a new record in each of the controller's page and when i click that link, i get this error.
I tried all methods given in the forums and online helps and still couldn't find a solution to this mess.

Below is the code i have written in w2-store/app/views/admin/layouts/admin.php :

```
<div class="wrap">

<?php $this->display_flash(); ?>

<?php $controller = $this->name; ?>

<?php $this->render_main_view(); ?>

<?php echo $this->name; ?>

<?php

if($name = 'admin_countries') {
    $controller = 'countries';
    echo '<a href="admin.php?page=mvc_countries-add">Add New</a>';
}
elseif ($name = 'admin_currencies') {
    $controller = 'currencies';
    echo '<a href="admin.php?page=mvc_currencies-add">Add New</a>';

}
elseif ($name = 'admin_zones') {
    $controller = 'zones';
    echo '<a href="admin.php?page=mvc_zones-add">Add New</a>';

}

?>
</div>
```

can any one suggest me a solution?
Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for myself.

The reason i got this error was because i have added a custom menu in bootstrap.php and it was in conflict with the permissions. I just removed the unwanted menu item and the error was no more.

to be more clear,

I have a custom menu in my bootstrap.php like this:

```
MvcConfiguration::append(array(
  'AdminPages' => array(
        'countries' => array(
     'in_menu' => true,
        'parent_slug' => 'mvc_mystores'
          ),
    'mystores' => array(
            'countries',
            'currencies',
            'zones'
        )
  )
));
```

in the above code, the following lines served no purpose but were promptly generating error message which is our topic of discussion:

```
 'countries' => array(
 'in_menu' => true,
    'parent_slug' => 'mvc_mystores'
      ),
```

I just removed that.

Now its okay.

Thanks everyone.